# wget postdata no such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell, wget

```
"wget --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'dir="$dir1"=&file="$file1"' --no-check-certificate http://test.com/mp3/file.php"
```

in command line everything working fine but in shell script its showing no such file or directory

> wget --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data
>   'dir=L011c2ljYW5fU2luZ2VyL1N1amF0aGEgSGl0cw===&file=S2FhdHJ1IEthYXRydSAtIElzYWlBcnV2aS5OZXQubXAz'
>   --no-check-certificate http://test.com/mp3/file.php : No such file or directory

Comment: `wget --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'dir="$dir1"=&file="$file1"' --no-check-certificate "http://test.com/mp3/file.php"`

Comment: same error coming @jDo

Comment: That error looks like you actually wrapped the command in quotes when you tried to run it so the shell didn't split it on words and run it. (Try running `"wget word word word"` with the quotes from the shell for example.) Is that what happened?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the double quote before `wget` is a formatting mistake (`"wget --user-a ...`) or actually part of your command; either way, remove it. Also, try double quoting the URL. This works for me on the command line and in a shell script:

```
 wget --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'dir="$dir1"=&file="$file1"' --no-check-certificate "http://test.com/mp3/file.php"
```

Running a script containing the command:

```
user@box:~$ sh wget_script.sh 
--2016-04-26 14:28:42--  http://test.com/mp3/file.php
Resolving test.com (test.com)... 69.172.200.235
Connecting to test.com (test.com)|69.172.200.235|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://www.test.com/ [following]
--2016-04-26 14:28:42--  https://www.test.com/
Resolving www.test.com (www.test.com)... 69.172.200.235
Connecting to www.test.com (www.test.com)|69.172.200.235|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘file.php’

    [ <=>                                                                                                          ] 1,557       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2016-04-26 14:28:42 (92.4 MB/s) - ‘file.php’ saved [1557]

user@box:~$
```

Comment: Location: http://test.com/mp3//load/v*%F5/~)^ [following]
Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.

Comment: dir1=L011c2ljYW5fU2luZ2VyL1N1amF0aGEgSGl0cw== file2=S2FhdHJ1IEthYXRydSAtIElzYWlBcnV2aS5OZXQubXAz

Comment: im only using two varaibles see above comment

Comment: @SatSam There's an asterisk here: `test.com/mp3//load/v*` <--- wildcard

Comment: @SatSam No, if I understand it correctly, base 64 either adds 0, 1 or 2 `=` depending the number_of_bytes modulus 3. As I wrote in my answer, I think your first error was caused by double quoting the command and not quoting the URL (that part is solved now, right?). As I wrote in the previous comment, I think the second error is caused by the parts of the script that we're *not* seeing; the `sed` command that used `*`. I don't think it produces the output you're expecting.

Comment: first error is solved and second one with sed i echo two varaible and both are showing correct

Comment: @SatSam ...but it still isn't working or what do you mean? If that's the case, add the new information to the question (your `sed` command and the errors you're getting) or make a new question since the first one has been solved.

Comment: change:

--post-data 'email=$dir1&password=$file1'

to:

--post-data "email=$dir1&password=$file1"

Comment: about changes solved the error.. thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding wget's path will help:

```
which wget
```

will return e.g. `/usr/bin/wget`. Try adding that path to your command line.

Comment: This isn't the issue. `wget` is found and runs but OP is either passing in an invalid URL (by trying to use globbing) or is being redirected to an invalid URL

Comment: @jDo Maybe you're right, yet the OP is to decide what's helpful. In any case, using the full path for commands is good practice in shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

define your variable inside script also. ( dir1= and file= )

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1="bla"
file="blabl.bla"

wget --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'dir="$dir1"=&file="$file1"' --no-check-certificate http://test.com/mp3/file.php
```